# Error saving a new Business Unit in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm creating a new Business unit in Marketing Cloud. I have selected the existing Main account as the parent to the new BU. When i save, i get the error message "Invalid parent id XXXX provided to ENTERPRISE_2 account XXXX"

Any ideas why?

Comment: it sounds like a bug - tried logging in and out again?

Comment: I can't believe, but it worked after logging out and back in!!

Comment: haha awesome! :) Added as answer so the question can be marked as resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when it fails to establish links it's because it "loses" the Id's behind the scenes. Logging out and back in can sometimes resolve some of the issues.

In other areas of the application, switching studios, will achieve the same